# How to make atomic writes to blob storage and database?

Tags: database, acid, blobstorage

I'd like to have a method which writes files to blob storage (e.g. S3, minIO) and associated metadata to a database (e.g. mongoDB). If either write fails, none should succeed. In other words, this combined write should be atomic.

There are some relevant, very old posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804858/how-to-do-azure-blob-storage-and-azure-sql-db-atomic-transaction), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084890/file-uploading-as-an-atomic-operation)) with proposed solution outlines. However, I assume that this must be a super common scenario, so maybe now there's already a robust, proven and easy-to-use library?